# Batch: Empty Folder and then Add Files?

Tags: batch-file, backup, directory, xcopy

I'm trying to create a batch file that will empty the contents of directoryX, and then copy all of the contents of directoryZ into directoryX. Will this work on Win8?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.  I called mine EmptyAndReplace.cmd (use .CMD instead of .BAT extension).

```
@ECHO OFF

TITLE Backup Files to USB Drive

DEL /Q /F /S C:\directoryX\*.*
REM /Q to not prompt if OK to delete *.*
REM /F to force delete of Read-Only files
REM /S to traverse subdirectories

XCOPY /V /E /H C:\directoryZ\*.* C:\directoryX
REM /V to verify file size
REM /E to traverse subdirectories, including Empty directories
REM /H to copy hidden files
REM /Q if you don't want each copied filename printed

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    COLOR CF
    PAUSE
    )
```

There are other command-line switches to use if you want to include subdirectories or deal with read-only files.  You can type "help del" and "help xcopy" at the command prompt to see all of your options.

I tested on Windows 8, though it should work on any version of Windows that you can still find running.

Comment: I am interested in copying hidden and read only files and all subfolders. I'm guessing in this case I won't need to make changes? I'm using this .cmd as a quick way to backup my USB drive - is this an appropriate approach?

Comment: Yes, it does require changes to handle hidden and read-only files as well as subdirectories. I have already made those changes in the answer. And it certainly is an approach, but not sure if it is the best one. There are programs that will sync between drives, only making changes rather than brute-force copying items that haven't changed. A quick search turned up this list -- http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2419298,00.asp#Backup/Sync -- and also this option: http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/ . Just search for "free sync software".

Comment: And for what you are wanting to do, maybe removing the /Q from the DEL would be best.

Comment: What would I need to add if I were to add a popup if the drive isn't found to assure that I've backed everything up?

Comment: Do you mean if the destination drive isn't found?  It will display an "Invalid Drive Specification" error. I have made 2 more updates to the script to title the window and if there is an error copying, it will change the window color and pause until you hit a key so it is very noticeable. I assume you will just be double-clicking on the CMD script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the folder then this should work:

```
@echo off
rd /s /q "directoryX"
ren "directoryZ" "directoryX"
```

If you want to copy the files then try this instead:

```
@echo off
rd /s /q "directoryX"
xcopy "directoryZ\*.*" "directoryX\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

Comment: +1 Simple, and does the job perfectly. However he did specify "`copy`". Look at my suggested edit.